# Selenium Chromedriver and IEdriver No Such Window exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having this issue in selenium where the original window is getting closed instead of a new window that is open and targeted. The code runs smoothly on firefox. But in Chrome (really fast) and IE it fails with an exception: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window.

I think it has something to do with the speed of the test? So, chrome tries super fast when closing the window? How do you actually close the new window and switch back to the original one and interact with it?

Here is the snippet of my code.

```
 try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
String originalWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
String newWindow;
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> stringIterator = windowHandles.iterator();

while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
    newWindow = stringIterator.next();
    if (!originalWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(newWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
        System.out.println("The title of the page is: “ + driverInstance.getTitle());
      }

}
driver.close(); ///In here I should close the new window 

driver.switchTo().window(originalWindow); ///In here I should switch back to the old window
```

Comment: So, chrome fails right after driver.close(); because after that I am switching to the original window and interacting with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try waiting e.g.

Try adding via Explicit wait

```
void checkAlert() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //exception handling
    }
}

Or 
implicit wait
    driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS
```

);

```
Or 
with thread sleep : 
    driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used thread.sleep because other solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do over with new info...

I don't know if this will work because I haven't done a lot with popups but I would start with something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // navigate to the page that spawns popups

    while (driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 1)
    {
        // we're waiting for a popup to be spawned
    }

    closePopups(driver);
}

private static void closePopups(WebDriver driver)
{
    // closes all browser windows other than the main window, e.g. popups
    // NOTE: it will not close other instances of the same browser, only those spawned by the current driver

    String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
        if (!handle.equals(currentHandle))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle).close();
        }
    }

    driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
}
```

Comment: So basically, I should say driver.switchTo().window(newWindow).close(); in terms of my code?

Comment: That's what worked for me... and hopefully will work for you if you don't want to use the full function. Try it and see... let me know the result.

Comment: It's still the same problem. I am just having a waiting issue. The code works fine in firefox, just chrome is too fast to handle the windows.

Comment: Edited my answer to add another suggestion. Try waiting for the popup to exist, then close it.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I'm kind of confused with this. Can you explain it to me with my case? Where do I wait and when do I close the newWindow?

Comment: Jeff, the code is still failing. The problem is chromedriver is too fast to handle these multiple windows. When I debug this code it shows me that I have two windowHandles when the pop up is open too. Then I say close the pop up it closes. Everything is working fine when debugging. But when I run it, chrome is super fast and shows me 1 window open when there is actually two.  I need a way to stop when the pop up is open so chrome calms down a little bit. I don't want to use Thread.sleep();

Comment: If what you say is true, put a `Thread.Sleep(200);` right above where the `.close()` is done and see if it actually works. If it does, then just leave it. Sometimes you have to use sleeps, I just avoid them as much as possible and prefer waits.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. I am using sleep right now.

Comment: You should update your question with what else you have tried.. include code and results/errors for each attempt.